How to match letters, digits, dashes, semicolons, dots and commas together but not if without digits and letters?
for example this is my method
import re
text = "ONE:;TWO:,,d,-;THREE:fsdfsd;FOUR:43879293847;FIVE:dsa. dsa, 56;SIX: ;SEVEN:,,,;EIGHT:--;"

def parser(string):
    prepare = []
    string = list(filter(None, string.split(";")))
    for i in string:
        s = i.split(":")
        j = len(list(filter(None, s)))
        if j == 2 and re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9_-]*$",s[1]):
            prepare.append(i)

    final = ";".join(prepare) + ";"
    return final
        
print(parser(text))

it only returns THREE,FOUR and EIGTH, but I also want to include TWO and FIVE and exclude EIGTH.
May be it is not the best method to approach my goal, but how to include TWO and FIVE in it but not SEVEN and EIGTH?
Thank you in advance.

For your existing code, you could check if the second part has either a digit or a number using re.search and the character class [A-Za-z0-9]
import re

text = "ONE:;TWO:,,d,-;THREE:fsdfsd;FOUR:43879293847;FIVE:dsa. dsa, 56;SIX: ;SEVEN:,,,;EIGHT:--;"


def parser(string):
    prepare = []
    string = list(filter(None, string.split(";")))
    for i in string:
        s = i.split(":")
        j = len(list(filter(None, s)))
        if j == 2 and re.search("[A-Za-z0-9]", s[1]):
            prepare.append(i)

    final = ";".join(prepare) + ";"
    return final


print(parser(text))

Output
TWO:,,d,-;THREE:fsdfsd;FOUR:43879293847;FIVE:dsa. dsa, 56;


As an alternative with a single regex:
[\w .,-]+:[\w .,-]*[^\W_][\w .,-]*;

Explanation

[\w .,-]+ Match 1+ times any of the listed characters
: Match a colone
[\w .,-]* Match 0+ times any of the listed character
[^\W_] Match a single word character excluding an underscore
[\w .,-]*; Match 0+ times any of the listed character followed by a semicolon

See a regex demo and a Python demo
Example:
import re

text = "ONE:;TWO:,,d,-;THREE:fsdfsd;FOUR:43879293847;FIVE:dsa. dsa, 56;SIX: ;SEVEN:,,,;EIGHT:--;"
regex = re.compile(r"[\w .,-]+:[\w .,-]*[^\W_][\w .,-]*;")


def parser(string):
    return "".join(re.findall(regex, string))


print(parser(text))

Output
TWO:,,d,-;THREE:fsdfsd;FOUR:43879293847;FIVE:dsa. dsa, 56;

